# Validates presence of not working in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I have a simple Rails app that has a model that is contained in several places. I allow the updating of the model from several different controllers in Rails 2.3.8. In my model I have code that allows for the name and the description to be validated. If they are blank Active_Scaffold should be populating the div with an error message. This works in the page that is linked directly to the User's controller but if I include the user anywhere else it will only show up on the User's controller page and not on the page that they are currently on. Shouldn't Acitive_Scaffold magically redirect to the correct place?

Code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :description, :allow_blank => false

    def create_from_params(params)
        @name = params[:name]
        @description = params[:description]
    end
```

As you can see nothing spectacularly hard.

EDIT: Sorry I left out the rest of the method signature

Comment: You don't need to overwrite the `create` method in the User model (ActiveRecord::Base brings you all these basics methods, such as create new update delete destroy etc.)

Comment: Sorry I edited it. I forgot part of the method signature.

Comment: This method `create_from_params(params)` is not usefull here, the basic `create` method of AR::Base is enough. Anyway, if you want to set the attributes of a Model, use `self.name = params[:name]` instead. But I recommend you to use the basic `create` method of AR::Base. Oh, and also finish with a `self.save` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the active_scaffold views only check for errors on the model it represents.  Add this error check code to any view but the user view.

```
<%= error_messages_for :user %>
```

Comment: Will this populate an active_scaffold error message properly?

Comment: I've never used active_scaffold before but I think if you try this it will reveal the issue.